# IDisposable / RAII in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

What is the idiomatic way of achieving deterministic clean-up in TypeScript? In other words, is there an equivalent of C#'s `using (IDisposable)` or C++'s RAII?

Or should I just stick to `finally`?

---

Context: In a SPA application (Aurelia / ASP.NET Core Web API), I'm trying to give an indication to the user that data is currently being fetched from the Web API. Once the fetch is finished, I'd like to remove the UI indication even if an exception has been thrown. I'm looking into wrapping that into a "RAII class" for reuse and cleaner syntax (so I don't have to pepper the code with `finally`)...

Comment: The ECMAScript [explicit-resource-management](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-explicit-resource-management) proposal should satisfy this use case.

Answer (score 5):

There is no `using` statement in Typescript, you can always fall back on `try-finally` which is what `using` is syntactic sugar for in C# anyway.

Another approach would be to create your own `using` with a function.

```
interface IDisposable {
    dispose();
}

function using<T extends IDisposable,
    T2 extends IDisposable,
    T3 extends IDisposable>(disposable: [T, T2, T3], action: (r: T, r2: T2, r3: T3) => void);
function using<T extends IDisposable, T2 extends IDisposable>(disposable: [T, T2], action: (r: T, r2: T2) => void);
function using<T extends IDisposable>(disposable: T, action: (r: T) => void);
function using(disposable: IDisposable[], action: (...r: IDisposable[]) => void)
function using(disposable: IDisposable | IDisposable[], action: (...r: IDisposable[]) => void) {
    let disposableArray = disposable instanceof Array ? disposable : [disposable];
    try {
        action(...disposableArray);
    } finally {
        disposableArray.forEach(d => d.dispose());
    }
}


// Usage
class UserNotify { dispose() { console.log("Done"); } }

class Other { dispose() { console.log("Done Other"); } }

using(new UserNotify(), userNotify => {
    console.log("DoStuff");
})
// It will type the arrow function parameter correctly for up to 3 parameters, but you can add more overloads above.
using([new UserNotify(), new Other()], (userNotify, other) => {
    console.log("DoStuff");
})
```

If you want to use it with promises, you could create an async version in which disposable returns a promise and the `action` parameter returns a promise as well:

```
interface IDisposableAsync {
    dispose(): Promise<void> | void;
}
function usingAsync<T extends IDisposableAsync, T2 extends IDisposableAsync, T3 extends IDisposableAsync>(disposable: [T, T2, T3], action: (r: T, r2: T2, r3: T3) => Promise<void>): Promise<void>;
function usingAsync<T extends IDisposableAsync, T2 extends IDisposableAsync>(disposable: [T, T2], action: (r: T, r2: T2) => Promise<void>): Promise<void>;
function usingAsync<T extends IDisposableAsync>(disposable: T, action: (r: T) => Promise<void>): Promise<void>;
function usingAsync(disposable: IDisposableAsync[], action: (...r: IDisposableAsync[]) => Promise<void>): Promise<void>
async function usingAsync(disposable: IDisposableAsync | IDisposableAsync[], action: (...r: IDisposableAsync[]) => Promise<void>): Promise<void> {
    let disposableArray = disposable instanceof Array ? disposable : [disposable];
    try {
        await action(...disposableArray);
    } finally {
        for (let d of disposableArray) {
            let result = d.dispose();
            if (result !== null) {
                await result;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Usage
class UserNotify { dispose() { console.log("Done"); } }
class Other { dispose() { console.log("Done Other"); } }
function delay() {
    return new Promise((r)=> setTimeout(() => {
        r();
    }, 100));
}
(async function () {
    await usingAsync(new UserNotify(), async userNotify => {
        await delay()
        console.log("DoStuff");
    })

    await usingAsync([new UserNotify(), new Other()], async (userNotify, other) => {
        await delay()
        console.log("DoStuff");
    })
})();
```

Comment: typescript does have `using` now: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-2-beta/#using-declarations-and-explicit-resource-management

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't language statements for it (like destructors and deterministic destruction). You have to use `try { ... } finally { ... }` statements for it.

If you want to know how it could be done in a way similar to C++, please take a look at https://github.com/cardinalby/ts-raii-scope when I tried to use RAII container and TypeScript decorators for that. But I'm not sure it's good for production code, because other developers could be confused with this approach.

Also I think it could be implemented by [TypeScript transforms](https://dev.doctorevidence.com/how-to-write-a-typescript-transform-plugin-fc5308fdd943)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WeakRef` with a timer to check if the object exists.

```
function registerObject(object) {
    console.log('Start!')
    const ref = new WeakRef(object)
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      // Check if object does not exist anymore
      if (!ref.deref()) {
        console.log('End!')
        clearInterval(id)
      }
      console.log(`${typeof ref.deref()}`)
    }, 1000)
}

{
  let a = new Date();
  registerObject(a)
}
```